# css3 animation text align center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a css3 animation on a custom text. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pwLxo78k/

As you can see, one part of the text's content is static ("I love") and the other part is set dynamically inside the animation.

I just want to keep my text centered, but I also want the static text ("I love") remains at the same position whatever the length of the dynamic text.

Is it possible with keeping the `text-align: center` property on my div ?

Thanks

Comment: i'm afraid it is not possible using text-align:center so try something like using paddings or margins or maybe using position, anyway here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pwLxo78k/4/

Comment: If I have understood the question properly. http://jsfiddle.net/g7tcfg2n/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Without position:
CSS:

```
#divHeader {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#divHeader span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:49%;
}
#fixedspan {
    text-align:right;
}
#movingspan {
    text-align:left;
}
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/pwLxo78k/9/

With positioning.
CSS:

```
#divHeader {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
#fixedspan {
    position:absolute;
    left:40%;
    width:38px;
}
#movingspan {
    position:absolute;
    left:calc(40% + 38px); //adjust the position based on width of "I love"
    margin:0 2px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pwLxo78k/6/

Comment: If you resize the page the position will not be exactly center.

Comment: Not exactly. You changed the complete HTML

Comment: No problem dude. @KK Your answer is not dynamic, it's based on the width of the text. And you changed the whole CSS lol.

Comment: @RaeenHashemi Suit yourself!

Comment: It should be noted that this is not a game. The point is helping the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`tables`** for something like this:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr style="width: 100%">
        <td style="width: 50%">
            <div id="fixedspan">I love</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="movingspan" class="moving">you</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And use:

```
#fixedspan {
    text-align: right;
}

#movingspan {
    text-align: left;
}
```

for the css. And use **`div`** instead of **`span`** for the `text-align` to work. Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3cky3po6/2/).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pwLxo78k/8/

```
#divHeader {
text-align: center;
width:35%;
margin:0 auto;
}


#fixedspan {
   float:left;
}
```